# Introductory text about different stratification methods in higher-order logic and set theory

Tags: reference-request, logic, higher-order-logic, type-theory

Could someone recommend me a good overview text about stratification of predicates, comprehension axioms, and other methods of avoiding the paradoxes in untyped or only loosely/relatively typed higher-order logics and/or different foundations of set theory?

I'm dealing with more philosophical theories of predication where the authors use second-order logics with stratified predicates in comprehension schemes instead of type theory, and I'd like to better understand these approaches. I'm familiar with basic concepts of mathematical logic (e.g. Andrew's book) but not a mathematician. So it shouldn't be too hard. :o

Comment: Hmm, no answers here, maybe you should try mathoverflow.net. Use "reference-request" as another tag. Leave out the bit about not being a mathematician. ;-)